# Run both doctests and normal tests with Pytest

Tags: python, pytest, python-sphinx, doctest

In my Python project, I'm using Pytest. The directory structure is:

```
src/
docs/
test/
```

I have a different kind of tests:

1. normal tests, in `test/*`
2. doctests in the source, `src/*`
3. doctests in documentation, `docs/*.rst` (Sphinx)

I'd like to run all of them at once, so I can aggregate statistics on all of them (e.g. coverage).

- For 1. : just `pytest`
- For 2. : `pytest --doctest-modules src`
- For 3. : `pytest --doctest-glob="docs/*.rst" docs`

I managed to run pairs of them:

- For 1-2: `pytest --doctest-modules src test`
- For 1-3: `pytest --doctest-glob="docs/source/*.rst"`

How to run all of them in one single command? Maybe the problem is simpler than I think...