# Pytest run tests and doctests with coverage

Tags: pytest, doctest, pytest-cov

I want to run pytest with coverage (pytest-cov) for my set of tests (stored in ./test) + doctests (stored in ./myproj/*.py) in a single command but I seem to be unable to get it to work

Running the unittests separately and appending the results from doctest works fine e.g.

```bash
pytest --cov=myproj --cov-report=html --cov-report=xml --cov-context=test
pytest --cov=myproj --cov-report=html --cov-report=xml --cov-append --doctest-modules
```

for CI this is fine bug for local testing it is rather annoying to have to type the second command every time.

Attempting to combine the two commands e.g.

```bash
pytest --cov=myproj --cov-report=html --cov-report=xml --cov-context=test --doctest-modules myproj
```

only runs the doctests.

Am I missing something obvious?

---

1. Similar issue (lacking an answer): [Run both doctests and normal tests with Pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53743920/run-both-doctests-and-normal-tests-with-pytest)
2. Similar issue (solution not working): [How to make pytest run doctests as well as normal tests directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17056138/how-to-make-pytest-run-doctests-as-well-as-normal-tests-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of searching it dawned on me that I had to include both `myproj` and `test` directories and now coverage includes both tests and doctests

```bash
pytest myproj test --cov=myproj --cov-report=html --cov-report=xml --cov-context=test --doctest-modules
```